# Proxy issue for generating PDF from XHtml source text using Flying Saucer

Tags: java, pdf, proxy, flying-saucer

I am facing some problem to generate a PDF using FLying Saucer from a XHTML source.

I use the working following code :

```
ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();

renderer.setDocumentFromString(pageSourceCode);
```

I would like to include some images in my source for the pdf to be generated. It implies having a href pointing to the images.

It seems that the href to the image has to be the complete URL else it does not find the image. On my local environment, I got no problem to generate the pdf with the image, but on the distant farm of server wich is behind a proxy, I have no image.

1. It does not recognize the URL used from the web (https://mydomain.com/mysite/...)
2. Using the server name + port works but is dirty since I have a farm of server (2 cluster with different port). So I can never determine which server is providing the data. If I point to a single server and if that server goes down, I won t have the image any more.
3. I have tried to configure a http/https proxy on the server jvm.properties (used for tomcat configuration) but it did not work.

My configuration :

tomcat5.5.28
jre1.6_13
Usage of https for all navigation
Usage of a proxy
java.args=-Duser.language=fr -Duser.region=FRx -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaPermSize=128m -Dhttp.proxyHost=myProxy -Dhttp.proxyPort=80 -Dnetworkaddress.cache.ttl=300  -DnonProxyHosts=myServerHost -Dhttps.nonProxyHosts=myServerHost-Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=myServerHost

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried "http://localhost:"+request.getServerPort()+"/mysite/etc"